# Export org-mode to LaTeX without preamble and document environment

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have recently started using org-mode as an electronic lab notebook for my work, and would like to combine these files with the files that I have set up in my old lab notebook, which was done in LaTeX.

The way my old notebook works is that each day goes under a file, e.g. `20161129.tex`, and this file is added to the notebook using the `\input{}` command, so there is no preamble or `\begin{document}` in `20161129.tex`, and it just starts with `\section{2016-11-29 Tuesday}`.

Given my file in `org-mode`, e.g.,

```
* Logbook
:PROPERTIES:
:DATE_TREE:
:END:
** 2016
*** 2016-11 November
**** 2016-11-29 Tuesday
***** Validation cases for subgrid
Some text and some math ($a + b = c$) to export.
```

I would like to export the 2016-11-09 subtree so that the resulting TeX file only contains the following content:

```
\section{2016-11-29  Tuesday}
Some text and some math ($a + b = c$) to export.
```

Preferably, this would be auto-exported and saved with the date (`2016-11-29.tex`), but having the same thing in a LaTeX buffer would be almost as good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-c C-e` opens the export dialog.

At that point, `C-b` to toggles 'body-only' - set this to 'on' to ignore all the preamble stuff.

And finally, `C-s` allows you to select the scope for export. In this case, select subtree and you should have what you're after:

> \section{2016-11-29 Tuesday}
>   \label{sec-1}
>   \subsection{Validation cases for subgrid}
>   \label{sec-1-1}
>   Some text and some math ($a + b = c$) to export.

For details, see [(org) The export dispatcher](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-Export-Dispatcher.html)

Comment: Thanks, swore that I had tried that before. I must have tried compiling with the 'body-only' option which threw an error. Is there a way to set the level of the exported subtree to a section instead of title? If I set the cursor on the subtree for a specific day, it exports the tree name `2016-11-29 Tuesday` as the title, and I'd like it to be at the section level.

Comment: See my update -that's what I am getting, with emacs -Q. It does seem to be fussy about where point is when you call the exporter, sometimes it takes the child of the current subtree instead of the subtree i'm on ?

Comment: Interesting, I still have the same issue running `emacs -Q`. My first section is `\section{Validation cases for subgrid}`. Guess I will need to look into this a little more and report back.

Comment: I've marked this as correct, as it does 99% of what I need. The one thing I was not able to get was consistent behavior of getting the sections correct. To remedy this, after I am done with a day I add the `:noexport:` tag to the daily subtree header, and then export from the monthly subtree using the process Tyler outlined. This gets me the behavior I want with minimal fuss.