# Remove default org-mode LaTeX preamble when rendering

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am currently playing around with `org-mode` in Spacemacs to render some file as LaTeX. I want to add a preamble and a new function to change the default `\maketitle` `org-mode` uses.

I am using a `#+SETUPFILE` so my org file looks like:

```
#+SETUPFILE: ../setup_file.org

<-content here->
```

In my `setup_file.org` I include all the headers, including some `LATEX_HEADERS` that will call my custom preamble and my `\psetheader` function:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil 
#+STARTUP: align fold nodlcheck hidestars oddeven lognotestate 
#+LATEX_HEADER: \documentclass[11pt]{article}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \input{../header.tex}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \psetheader
#+KEYWORDS: orgmode pdf latex
#+LANGUAGE: en
```

Finally, the `header.tex` file just includes the packages I need and the `\psetheader` command. Now, the rendering fails, it produces a document, but is not quite there. When I open the `.tex` file, I find that `org` has included a preamble on top:

```
% Created 2023-04-07 Fri 19:37
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input{../header.tex}
\psetheader
```

I have tried to just render just the body, as [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29016/export-org-mode-to-latex-without-preamble-and-document-environment) post suggests, but then no preamble is rendered into the `.tex` file and it fails to build. There is an option to just make `nil` the default preamble temporarily? I have tried to create a `org-latex-class`, but it does not play nice with my header command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you specify `\documentclass` as a `#+LATEX_HEADER` in your setup file. Instead, you should specify it in two pieces, [using `#+LATEX_CLASS` and `#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS`](https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-export-settings.html)[1]:

```org
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil 
#+STARTUP: align fold nodlcheck hidestars oddeven lognotestate 
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [11pt]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \input{../header.tex}
#+KEYWORDS: orgmode pdf latex
#+LANGUAGE: en
```

After that, you don't have to worry about zeroing out the default preamble. It will consist of `\usepackage` declarations that will load the packages into TeX's memory, but if you don't use them, they'll just sit there, bothering noone.

If you really want to zero it out, overriding the `article` class in `org-latex-classes` is indeed the way to go, but I suggest you don't go there unless you really have to.

Finally, in order to impose a new title structure, you can either redefine `\maketitle` in your own `header.tex` and leave it at that. But since you seem to want your own command `\psetheader`, then you can redefine the variable `org-latex-title-command` whose default value is `"\\maketitle"` (remember that backslashes have to be escaped with another backslash in an elisp string). Use customize preferably (or set it in your init file: `(setq org-latex-title-command "\\psetheader")` ). Assuming `\psetheader` works like `\maketitle`, it does *NOT* go in the preamble, so you don't add it as a `#+LATEX_HEADER` in your setup file: it has to be inserted right after the `\begin{document}`. Redefining the `org-latex-title-command` is the way to accomplish that.

---

[1] See also [LaTeX header and sectioning structure](https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-header-and-sectioning.html) for a specific example.